Version code 105: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: App Activity Data Type - Apps On Device
We found an issue in the following area(s):
Version code 105: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: App Activity Data Type - Apps On Device
About the Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy
Your app must be in compliance with this policy. If your app continues to be non-compliant, your app updates will be rejected and your app may face additional enforcement actions in the future.
Please make changes to align your app’s Data safety form with the app’s behavior. This can be done by either:
Updating your form in Play Console to declare collection of Data Types noted below; or
Removing unwanted functionality and attributable code that collects this user data from your app or libraries used in your app, and when applicable to deactivate all non-compliant APKs.
To deactivate non-compliant APKS, you can create a new release and upload a compliant APK to each track containing the non-compliant APKs.
Be sure to increment the APK version code. If using staged rollout, be sure to set the release to 100% rollout.enter image description here
What should I do? What settings are needed?
https://play.google.com/console
I have chosen as many options as possible
